# How does Content Type Inheritance interact with retention policies?

Tags: content-type, information-management

Are there any issues with defining retention policies on a hierarchy of custom Content Types? I want to be able to define retention policies in a flexible manner, with a root Content Type that has the generic (probably non-existent) retention policy, then child Content Types that can (and some will, but others might not) define a separate retention policy. Will this work?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Yes; this is possible.

Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff363732.aspx (section: Defining content types)

Comment: The section referred to talks about multiple sub-types for different records. The concern I have is with a retention policy on the **parent** type. If I have one defined there, rather than on each child, will the children without explicitly defined policies inherit the policy from the parent, and will the one with a separate policy not inherit. If so, I'm great. If not, I have to define all the child policies, and not one on the parent. I just need to be aware of the right way to do this.